# VC++: How to display a control on the top of the propertySheet in MFC diaolg

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

All

i have a doubt on property sheet in VC++. i have 2 or more mfc dialogs and i merged those dialogs in one dialog as a tab control through property sheet. can i place a control on the top of the property sheet ? is it possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `CPropertySheet`, you can add your controls in the `OnCreate` handler (as described on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh5bb2bf.aspx)):

```
int CMyPropertySheet::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    int ret = CPropertySheet::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct);
    if(ret != 0)
        return ret;
    CRect rect;
    GetWindowRect(rect);
    // ... adjust rect here...
    MoveWindow(rect);
    // ... move tab control down here ...
    // ... add your controls above the tabctrl here ...
}
```